# Get Data after some specific row in laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model in 'Laravel' called *User* and table schema is below

```
+----+------+-------+---------+
| id | name | email | address |
+----+------+-------+---------+
|  1 | data | data  | data    |
|  2 | data | data  | data    |
|  3 | data | data  | data    |
|  4 | data | data  | data    |
+----+------+-------+---------+
```

I want to get 10 rows after specific row id. For example, I want 10 row after `id=3`. How do I write eloquent code for that?

Comment: What have you already tried? SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: show your code, what you have tried so far to achieve your goal!!!

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post.

The SO community values when you show your own efforts, so you might want to add some code. 



Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You should read documentation or at least google before posting a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a query how you can do it. Taking 10 rows after id=3

```
 User::where('id','>=',3)->take(10)->get();
```

You can modify the query. I have taken 10 rows after id=3 including id=3